# Call and use uitableview from uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with many UITableViewCell. Each Cell have a UISwitch Button.

Here is my UITableViewController Class:

```
@implementation DanhsachTableViewController{
    NSMutableArray *data;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        DichVu2TableViewCell *cell = (DichVu2TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dscell"];
        NSDictionary *dataCell =  data[indexPath.row];
        cell.service =  dataCell[@"service"];
        cell.package =  dataCell[@"package"];
        cell.loai_goi = dataCell[@"loai_goi"];

        return cell;
    }
-(void) changeCellState:(NSString *)service package:(NSString *)package loaigoi:(NSString *)loai_goi{
    for (int i =0;i<data.count;i++){
        DichVu2TableViewCell *cellLocal = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        if ([service isEqualToString:cellLocal.service] && ![package isEqualToString:cellLocal.package] && [loai_goi isEqualToString:cellLocal.loai_goi]){
            [cellLocal.sudung setOn:NO animated:YES];
        }
     }
}
```

"Data" array was loaded in method loadData (not important here so I don't include it).

In UITableViewCell (class name: DichVu2TableViewCell), I set event Value Change of Switch so that each time a Switch change value (ON for example), all other cell's switch which have the same value "service" and "loai_goi" will be set OFF.

```
DanhsachTableViewController *tableview = [[DanhsachTableViewController alloc] init];
    tableview.tableView.delegate = (DanhsachTableViewController *)self.superview.superview;
[tableview changeCellState:_service package:_package loaigoi:_loai_goi];
```

But when I call, the array "data" of above tableview have 0 object so nothing happened.

Is there any way to do that?

**Hi Oyeoj,
Thanks for your help.**

I have a little problem when followed your guide. There are some error in xcode when I use extract your code so I have to customize. But the program still has error when running. Would you please help me review my code. Thanks in advance.

DichVu2TableViewCell.h

```
@class DichVu2TableViewCell;
//Change : NSObject to <NSObject> because XCode 6.3 has error.
@protocol DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)changeCell:(DichVu2TableViewCell *)sender state:(NSString *)service package:(NSString *)package loaigoi:(NSString *)loai_goi;

@end

@interface DichVu2TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak) id <DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

DichVu2TableViewCell.m

```
@implementation DichVu2TableViewCell
….
- (void)someSwitchingEvent
{
    [self.delegate changeCell:self state:_service package:_package loaigoi:_loai_goi];
}
@end
```

DanhsachTableViewController.h

```
@interface DanhsachTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *loaitb;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property NSMutableArray *pre_inuse_;
@property NSMutableArray *data_inuse_;
@property NSMutableArray *vas_inuse_;
@end
```

DanhsachTableViewController.m

```
#import "DichVu2TableViewCell.h"
//Change <DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate> to (DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate) because XCode 6.3 has error.
@interface DanhsachTableViewController (DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate)
@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *forUpdateIndexPath;
@end

@implementation DanhsachTableViewController{
    NSMutableArray *data;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DichVu2TableViewCell *cell = (DichVu2TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dscell"];
    NSDictionary *dataCell =  data[indexPath.row];
    cell.service =  dataCell[@"service"];
    cell.package =  dataCell[@"package"];
    cell.loai_goi = dataCell[@"loai_goi"];
    cell.kieu_goi = dataCell[@"kieu_goi"];

    [cell.sudung setOn:NO animated:YES];
    cell.delegate = self;
//Change cellLocal —> cell because there are no cellLocal avaiable. And Program error when run to this row.
    [cell.sudung setOn:(self.forUpdateIndexPath == indexPath) animated:YES];

    return cell;
}

-(void)changeCell:(DichVu2TableViewCell *)sender state:(NSString *)service package:(NSString *)package loaigoi:(NSString *)loai_goi
{
//Add cellLocal —> cell because there are no cellLocal avaiable
    DichVu2TableViewCell *cellLocal = (DichVu2TableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.forUpdateIndexPath];
    if ([service isEqualToString:cellLocal.service] && ![package isEqualToString:cellLocal.package] && [loai_goi isEqualToString:cellLocal.loai_goi]){
        // get the indexPath of the cell
        self.forUpdateIndexPath =  [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        // update the date source
        NSMutableDictionary *dataCell =  [data[self.forUpdateIndexPath.row] mutableCopy];
        [dataCell setObject:service forKey:@"service"];
        [dataCell setObject:package forKey:@"package"];
        [dataCell setObject:loai_goi forKey:@"loai_goi"];
        // you dont need the for-statement just reload the table
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        // then update the switch inside `- cellForRowAtIndexPath`
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient method would be to use custom delegates.

1. You can declare a protocol in your `UITableViewController` class.
2. Declare the `changeCellState` function in the protocol.
3. Create a delegate property in the `UITableViewCell` class.
4. Call the delegate method from the `UITableViewCell` class when the switch value is changed.
5. The `UITableViewController` will itself receive the message, and the function will be called respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I used delegate sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging `self.superview.superview;` ? are your sure is in type `UIViewController`?

if so:

Do not call `[[DanhsachTableViewController alloc]`

instead use the `DanhsachTableViewController` from your parentview

```
DanhsachTableViewController *tableview = (DanhsachTableViewController *)self.superview.superview;
[tableview changeCellState:_service package:_package loaigoi:_loai_goi];
```

This

`DanhsachTableViewController *tableview = [[DanhsachTableViewController alloc] init];` assigns a *new* `DanhsachTableViewController` class and not the existing one.

**Edit**

USING `protocol` and `delegate`

When using delegate you dont need the `self.superview.superview` :)

> UNDER DichVu2TableViewCell

```
@class DichVu2TableViewCell; 

@protocol DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)changeCell:(DichVu2TableViewCell *)sender state:(NSString *)service package:(NSString *)package loaigoi:(NSString *)loai_goi;

@end

@interface DichVu2TableViewCell : UIViewController

@property (weak) id <DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implementaion DichVu2TableViewCell

..

- (void)someSwitchingEvent
{
    [self.delegate changeCell:self state:_service package:_package loaigoi:_loai_goi];
}

@end
```

while

> UNDER DanhsachTableViewController

```
// assuming you alreading imported the `DichVu2TableViewCell` like 
//
// #import "DichVu2TableViewCell.h"
//
// set the delegate

@interface DanhsachTableViewController () <DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *forUpdateIndexPath;

@end

// then implement the method from the delegate under implementation file

@implementation DanhsachTableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *data;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DichVu2TableViewCell *cell = (DichVu2TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dscell"];
    NSDictionary *dataCell =  data[indexPath.row];
    cell.service =  dataCell[@"service"];
    cell.package =  dataCell[@"package"];
    cell.loai_goi = dataCell[@"loai_goi"];

    // this is the magic .. :)
    //--
    cell.delegate = self;

    [cell.sudung setOn:(self.forUpdateIndexPath == indexPath) animated:YES];
    //--

    return cell;
}

-(void)changeCell:(DichVu2TableViewCell *)sender state:(NSString *)service package:(NSString *)package loaigoi:(NSString *)loai_goi
{
    // `self.forUpdateIndexPath` is declared as property

   if ([service isEqualToString:service] && ![package isEqualToString:package] && [loai_goi isEqualToString:loai_goi]){

        // get the indexPath of the cell
        self.forUpdateIndexPath =  [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

        // update the date source
        NSMutableDictionary *dataCell =  [data[self.forUpdateIndexPath.row] mutableCopy];

        [dataCell setObject:service forKey:@"service"];
        [dataCell setObject:package forKey:@"package"];
        [dataCell setObject:loai_goi forKey:@"loai_goi"];

        // you dont need the for-statement just reload the table

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        // then the switch will be updated inside `- cellForRowAtIndexPath`
    }

}
```

Hope this is more helpful now.. :) Cheers...

Comment: selft.superview.superview is in UITableView. I use your code but it's not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I follow your code but it's not working. I had all my code above. Can you give a look to see what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh yes.. sorry i'd miss the `()` in the line `@interface DanhsachTableViewController () <DichVu2TableViewCellDelegate>`

the problem is the delegate is not implemented therefore it is not called. `cellLocal` is just for example.. sorry for confusing you, i should have clean my code, or at least added comments..

Comment: @SouchanMeijin: Glad to help.. i'm confuse which is the answer to your question though. Anyway.. Highfive! Cheers! :)

Comment: I used delegate with your help. But I remove use of "forUpdateIndexPath" because my business in changeCell doesn't need it. The array DATA has all the information I need, so I only need to for in DATA to process some change in this array, then I reload data in table view. Method cellForRowAtIndexPath do the rest of things.

Comment: Ahh.. Okay. Glad may effort helped you though.. Cheers for that sir.. :)